Creating nose snot/cough splashed effect on camera
I want to create a nose snot/cough/vomit splash effect on camera. The idea is that during gameplay NPC is gonna perform those actions on my first person view player. I was trying to modify below shader to have desired effect but I am struggling to change the color and position of droplets.
https://github.com/yumayanagisawa/Unity-Raindrops
https://github.com/yumayanagisawa/Unity-Raindrops/blob/master/Raindrop/Assets/Raindrop.shader

Here's what I am trying to achieve

Change position of droplets so that there is one or two blob in the middle and other droplets are splashing from it.
Change color of the droplets to have beige tone.
Remove vertical lines (Those are only appearing when I am using lerp at the end of the frag. Guessing it's a performance issue)


Questions about how to get started or which assets or tools to use are considered off-topic. We can help you with things you're stuck on, but not with recommendations. For example, you could ask for help with changing the color and position of the droplets in the shader that you've referenced. If you edit your question in this way, it would be very helpful if you include a screenshot of what it looks like now, and an image or good description of how you want it to look.
